# Retrieving map of attributes in DOM 4

Tags: html, dom

Historically in the XML DOM for any `Element` one can call `element.getAttributes()` which will return a `NamedNodeMap`. This map allows you to iterate the `Node` instances, which in this case are `Attr` instances describing each attribute.

But when reading MDN's description of the [node type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) enumerated value for `Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE`, they say:

> An `Attribute` of an `Element`. Attributes no longer implement the `Node` interface as of DOM4.

Are they talking about `Attr`? But if `Attr` does not implement `Node` in DOM 4, what does `element.getAttributes()` return? A `NamedNodeMap` of nodes that are *not* instances of `Attr`?

Or does `Element` not have a `element.getAttributes()` method at all in DOM 4? If not, how does DOM 4 let me iterate through all the attributes? And is the code I'm writing in Java 11 using `element.getAttributes()` therefore eventually going to be out of date? And the same thing for JavaScript code I write in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's various points here.

DOM4 does indeed not contain a `getAttributes()` method on Element. It does, however, have a property called `attributes` which on accessing returns a NamedNodeMap.

"NamedNodeMap" seems a slightly misleading name since its items are `Attr` objects.

MDN is out of date. Earlier versions of the Attr interface in the DOM4 standard did not extend the Node interface, but it was found not to be web-compatible, and so now [the current definition of Attr](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#attr) does, just as DOM3 did.

Comment: The `getAttributes()` I was referring to was the Java binding of the DOM API, which I'm sure corresponds to the `attributes` property. So the answer seems to be that MDN is out of date and thereby incorrect. Thanks!